# Change time according time zone mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I am developing a website that gives statistics for soccer games,and i want to convert the schedule of the match depending on the time zone. I created this function but it seems not to be working.

```
public static DateTime UtcToLocalTimeZone(DateTime argDateTime,TimeZoneInfo argTimeZoneInfo)
{
    try
    {

        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(argDateTime, argTimeZoneInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return argDateTime;
    }

}
```

And this is how i display the date and time in my view:

```
 TimeZoneInfo timezone = (TimeZoneInfo)Session["timeZone"] ?? TimeZoneInfo.Local;
<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="id1" versus-id="@c.MatchID" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@homeMLName - @awayMLName">
                            @BetGuns.Web.Helper.UtcToLocalTimeZone(@c.MatchDate, timezone).ToString(dateFormat) <br />
                        @BetGuns.Web.Helper.UtcToLocalTimeZone(@c.MatchDate, timezone).ToString(timeFormat)
                    </a>
```

Comment: "it seems not to be working" gives us very, very little information. What is your input time? What's the input time zone? What's the expected output? What's the actual output? Is an exception being thrown? (Catching the exception like that and just ignoring it seems like a bad idea to me.)

Comment: It does not convert the time as excepted,it just take the time from the database and displays as it is.

Comment: it does not throw an exception.My input time is match time and time zone

Comment: Well the method won't throw an exception, because you're catching all exceptions. Are you saying that you're not hitting the catch block? If so, how have you determined that? I don't think you should have a try/catch at all. And I know what the input is meant to represent, but you should provide sample input, expected output and actual output. Ideally, provide a [mcve] (as a console app).